# How does the transclusion work here if transclude: false?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to learn more about advanced custom directives and I was looking through the following source code:

https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide/blob/master/dist/angular-pageslide-directive.js

I noticed that on line 11, `transclude: false,`

However, this directive is wrapped around a div.
How is the transclusion done?

the example given is thus:

```
<div ... ng-controller="yourCtrl">
    ...
    <pageslide ps-open="checked">
        <div>
            <p>some random content...</p>
        </div>
    </pageslide>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't use [`template`](https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide/blob/master/dist/angular-pageslide-directive.js#L26) as well. This means that `<pageslide>` children elements are still available in link, and they can be [manipulated](https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide/blob/master/dist/angular-pageslide-directive.js#L78).

Comment: I see so the contents are not overridden by the template so when it grabs the jQ object that's the child of slider it can manipulate the css of it to get the effect. Thanks!